# Is there a way to see requests made by Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to review the get requests made by an application via Microsoft Graph API? I imgaine there is a method possibly within PowerShell, but I'm unable to find clear documentation from Microsoft.

I attempted to view reporting within PowerShell but it seems to be rather limited. Ultimately, I would like to run a report of some sort to see a complete list of queries during a given period.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do that, the graph developer proxy https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-developer-proxy-community-preview/ works pretty well. You could also use something like fiddler to see the raw request. If you use the Graph SDK you can also implement your own log handler using the middleware included in the SDK https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/dev/docs/logging-requests.md